# Fram.Navigate vs new a Page instance win8.1 store app

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am having a `mainpage.xaml` that contains an *appbar** which is assigned from a reusable page *(ToolboxDeviceSelectionControlPage)*.

```
this.BottomAppBar = new ToolboxDeviceSelectionControlPage().BottomAppBar;
```

After using the *ToolboxDeviceSelectionControlPage*, I need to return a object to the mainpage. How can I do this?

I tried to use Fram.Navigate(MainPage, object). it crashes and throw: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You should not do this. You should define the app bars in the same page.. you can create an external user control with AppBar as base class and use this in your page xaml

Comment: why cant do this? I am actually using FindName method and register all event at MainPage

Comment: create a resource or user control that is an app bar, then reference it from there. Otherwise, put a frame inside the reusable page and navigate within the inner frame so that the reusable page is always there. Or implement a page's control template and add the app bar that way.